# noun+adverb or adjective+adverb or adverb+adverb

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs

There was a sentence and it ended with this:

(bla bla bla) ______ equally.

And the options are:

1. Exception.
2. Exceptional.
3. Exceptionally.

I wish I could provide the whole context, but this is all I can remember from my previous test.

Anyway, I chose *exceptionally equally* which sounds awkward to me. It doesn't matter to know the previous words, I mean, my point of my question is which one precedes the adverb "equally"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence feels awkward when looking at the first definition of 'exception':

- exception: a person or thing that is excluded from a general statement or does not follow a rule.

Using the first definition in a sentence feels clunky:

> At the dog show, both dogs fell below the height exception equally.

Because here, 'equally' feels unnecessary. Since both dogs failed to meet a height requirement with equal measure, there's no need to relate the degree to which they failed some binary (pass/fail) test.

But when looking at the **idiomatic phrase 'take exception'**:

- take exception: to object to something : to feel or express disagreement with or opposition to something, e.g.
  "Domi squirted water at fans from the penalty box and a fan took exception."

It seems 1. is the answer, e.g.:

> Both fans at the hockey game took exception equally.